Generate n random 2D points within a valid region
I want to generate a fixed number of random-uniformly distributed xy points within a valid mask.
The generated points should be continuous, i.e. can be "between pixels".
I'm looking for an efficient solution since this will be part of a pytorch training loop.
Say I need 100 valid points, my current solution looks like this:

Generate 500 random points
Sample each point and check if the value is >0.5 (within the valid region)
Throw away all invalid points and additionally all surplus points so I end up with 100

There must be a more efficient solution for this, right?
This is some example code to demo the problem:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Create example mask
valid_mask = np.ones((300, 400), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
center = (valid_mask.shape[1] // 2, valid_mask.shape[0] // 2)
angle = 30
rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(valid_mask, rotation_matrix, (valid_mask.shape[1], valid_mask.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# display image
cv2.imshow('mask', rotated_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# generate 500 random points
num_points = 500
points = np.random.rand(num_points, 2) * 2 - 1  # Scale to [-1, 1]

# Convert image and points to tensors
rotated_image_tensor = torch.tensor(rotated_image, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0) / 255  # Shape (1, 1, H, W)
points_tensor = torch.tensor(points, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)  # Shape (1, 1, N, 2)

# Use grid_sample to sample from the image at each point
sampled_values = F.grid_sample(rotated_image_tensor, points_tensor, mode='bilinear', padding_mode='zeros', align_corners=False)

# Squeeze to remove unnecessary dimensions and get actual values
sampled_values = sampled_values.squeeze().numpy()

# Filter points where the sampled value is greater than 0.01
valid_points = points[sampled_values > 0.5]
print(len(valid_points))

# Display valid points
rotated_image = cv2.cvtColor(rotated_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for point in valid_points:
    x, y = point
    x = int((x + 1) * rotated_image.shape[1] / 2)
    y = int((y + 1) * rotated_image.shape[0] / 2)
    cv2.circle(rotated_image, (x, y), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', rotated_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Any help would be appreciated.

Is this a representative example? If so, why do you scale the random numbers to be between -1 and 1 rather than to be within your valid region?

Also, in the future, slim down your code to only the important parts. CV has nothing to do with your actual question so it just distracts from the relevant parts of the code.

The points are scaled to [-1, 1] because that's the format grid_sample expects. (0, 0) is the image centre.
Yes, the example is representative.

You can directly treat your mask as the weights for a multinomial distribution and sample from it. Here is a minimal example:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

generator = torch.Generator()
generator.manual_seed(98237)

# Create example mask
mask = torch.zeros((256, 256))
mask[32:187, 53:123] = 1.
mask[150:220, 89:198] = 1.

n_samples = 10_000

# define the probability density function and sample
pdf = mask / mask.sum()

coords = torch.multinomial(pdf.flatten(), n_samples, replacement=True, generator=generator)

x, y = torch.unravel_index(coords, pdf.shape)
x_dithered = x + torch.rand(x.shape, generator=generator) - 0.5
y_dithered= y + torch.rand(y.shape, generator=generator) - 0.5

# Create a 2D histogram of the samples
hist = np.histogram2d(x_dithered, y_dithered, bins=(np.arange(0, 256), np.arange(0, 256)))[0]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
axes[0].imshow(mask, origin="lower", cmap="gray")
axes[0].set_title("Mask")

axes[1].imshow(hist, origin="lower", cmap="viridis")
axes[1].set_title("Samples")

Which gives:

The trick here is to convert the mask into a one dimensional probability mass function (PMF) and then sample the integer indices. Next convert those back to a two dimensional array indices using unravelling and add uniformly distributed noise to "smear" the position within the support of a single pixel.
This approach generalizes to arbitrary PMFs, not only masks.
I hope this helps!
